# What type of panel data model to run for forecasting on a site level basis?

Tags: time-series, forecasting, panel-data

I am trying to forecast monthly energy volume on a site-level basis (around 2,000 individual sites). I have monthly data for each site for at least two years. I also have attributes such as square footage, building type, cost, location, etc.

Do I need to run an individual model for each site for the forecast to be most accurate?

I will be using R to perform the analysis. Any suggestions, tips, information, etc. will be VERY appreciated as I am currently in information overload :).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe facebook's [Prophet](https://facebook.github.io/prophet/) would be useful?  According to the github site, prophet is a "tool for producing high quality forecasts for time series data that has multiple seasonality with linear or non-linear growth."  They claim it scales well.

I have not used it but plan on evaluating it at some point.